# App to log network user's file activities

Tags: macos, osx-lion

My employer recently purchased a Mac Pro server (2011 model) and we've installed OSX Lion Server from the Mac Appstore. I'm definitely no server admin, but I have been tasked with finding out the following:

- Can we monitor or log what users do? (i.e. open a file, copy a file.... or file-related tasks)
- Can we stop files from being copied? Or be alerted when this does occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we monitor or log what users do? (ie, open a file, copy a file.... or file-related tasks)

See "Auditing System Activity" in the [Mac OS X Security Configuration" guide](http://images.apple.com/support/security/guides/docs/SnowLeopard_Security_Config_v10.6.pdf)

You can also do things like `fs_usage -w -f filesys > cap.txt`

> Can we stop files from being copied? Or be alerted when this does occur?

No, copying is reading and then writing elsewhere. If people can read a file and have access to writeable media, they can copy it.